# Why is my node-red app returning 404 route error in ibm-cloud?

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

My node-red app in bluemix was working, but now it doesn't let me access the route. It worked before and I have not modified it.
I am getting this error:

```
404 Not Found: Requested route ('route.mybluemix.net') does not exist.
```

The recent logs are:

```
   2018-04-16T09:37:46.60-0300 [CELL/0] OUT Creating container
   2018-04-16T09:37:47.42-0300 [CELL/0] OUT Successfully created container
   2018-04-16T09:37:54.32-0300 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2018-04-16T09:37:55.41-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > node-red-bluemix@0.8.0 start /home/vcap/app
   2018-04-16T09:37:55.41-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT > node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v
   2018-04-16T09:37:55.62-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:55 - Starting Node-RED on IBM Cloud bootstrap
   2018-04-16T09:37:55.62-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:55 - Loading bluemix-settings.js
   2018-04-16T09:37:55.72-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:55 - Using Cloudant service: /^NodeRed.cloudantNoSQLDB/ : NodeRed
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.08-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - Loading application settings
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.22-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - Using runtime settings for adminAuth
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - [info] 
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Welcome to Node-RED
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - [info] Linux 4.4.0-109-generic x64 LE
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT ===================
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - [info] Node-RED version: v0.18.2
   2018-04-16T09:37:56.77-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:56 - [info] Node.js  version: v6.12.3
   2018-04-16T09:37:57.25-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:57 - [info] Loading palette nodes
   2018-04-16T09:37:59.99-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:59 - [warn] Missing node modules:
   2018-04-16T09:37:59.99-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:59 - [warn]  - node-red-contrib-telegrambot (2.7.3): telegram bot, telegram receiver, telegram command, telegram callback_query, telegram sender, telegram reply
   2018-04-16T09:37:59.99-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:59 - [warn]  - node-red-contrib-play-audio (2.2.4): play audio
   2018-04-16T09:37:59.99-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:59 - [warn]  - node-red-contrib-browser-utils (0.0.5): fileinject, microphone, camera
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.00-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] Installing module: node-red-contrib-play-audio, version: 2.2.4
   2018-04-16T09:37:59.99-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:37:59 - [info] Installing module: node-red-contrib-telegrambot, version: 2.7.3
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.21-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] Installing module: node-red-contrib-browser-utils, version: 0.0.5
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.30-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] Settings file  : /home/vcap/app/bluemix-settings.js
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.30-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] HTTP Static    : /home/vcap/app/public
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.44-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] Server now running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/red/
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.60-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info] Waiting for missing types to be registered:
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.60-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info]  - telegram bot
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.60-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info]  - telegram receiver
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.60-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info]  - telegram sender
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.60-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT 16 Apr 12:38:00 - [info]  - microphone
   2018-04-16T09:38:00.92-0300 [CELL/0] OUT Container became healthy
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.47-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR Killed
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! argv "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/node" "/home/vcap/app/vendor/node/bin/npm" "start"
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! node v6.12.3
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! node-red-bluemix@0.8.0 start: `node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v`
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Exit status 137
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! 
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Failed at the node-red-bluemix@0.8.0 start script 'node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v'.
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-red-bluemix package,
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! not with npm itself.
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.49-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js --settings ./bluemix-settings.js -v
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm bugs node-red-bluemix
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-red-bluemix
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.50-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.53-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.53-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] ERR npm ERR!     /home/vcap/app/npm-debug.log
   2018-04-16T09:38:03.61-0300 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Exit status 1 (out of memory)
```

Before I didn't have all this errors, I have not modified my nodes.

Comment: Have you logged into the console to look at it? Also are you on the free account?

Comment: Yes, I am on the free account. Also, if I go to the logs section in ibm-cloud I get that the latest result is a `> node --max-old-space-size=180 index.js "settings ./bluemix-
settings.js -v` And my app is not starting as usual, it is taking too long to start, and then it fails.

Comment: Edit the question to include the logs. It may also be useful to list any extra nodes you have added recently

Answer (score 1):

When Node-RED restarts in the IBM Cloud it has to check if it still has all the extra nodes added via the palette manager. That is because those nodes don't get added to the stored application image so are lost on a restage.

If it finds anything is missing, Node-RED will then dynamically reinstall them. You can see in the log it kicking off three reinstalls. This is where the problem is.

By installing these nodes in parallel, the application is most likely running out of memory and getting killed. For a lite account, you only have 256Mb to play with - which is not much.

You have two possible workarounds:

- enable the continuous delivery feature (last I looked, bottom right on the applications IBM Cloud dashboard page). That will give you a git repository you can edit the source in. Edit the `package.json` file to include these additional node modules under the `dependencies` section. That will ensure the nodes are installed as part of the application image and won't need reinstalling on restart.
- upgrade to a standard account where you'll be able to up your application to 512Mb of memory for free.

Since the Lite account was introduced with its 256Mb memory limit, we see this scenario more often. We will have to look at the reinstall code to see about making the installs happen sequentially rather than in parallel. It'll take longer, but should minimise the memory usage.